# jackson and jax-rs annotations

Tags: rest, jackson, jax-rs

I am using Jackson to implement a simple REST API.
Because it is the first time, I would like to be sure that I am following the correct practice.

Looking various examples, I found annotations implemented in the Jackson library such as @JsonProperty.
I found also other annotations that are defined in jax-rs.

It is not clear to me when Jackson ends and jax-rs starts and viceversa.
Is it ok to implement the API using both the annotations ?
Is there an overlapping or are always used to define different characteristics of the API?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JAX-RS is a specification for creating REST web services in Java. JAX-RS requires an implementation such as Jersey, RESTEasy or Apache CXF.

---

Jackson is a popular JSON parser for Java and can be integrated with JAX-RS using the [`jackson-jaxrs-providers`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jaxrs-providers) multi-module project.

---

While JAX-RS annotations allows you to map classes and methods to handle HTTP requests, Jackson annotations allows you to map Java classes to JSON objects and vice versa.

Comment: Ok. Does this mean that I can implement the API using only annotations in Jackson (and jackson-jaxrs-providers) ? Or, for example, the @GET annotation in the JAX-RS specification is used also in the implementation given by jackson-jaxrs-providers?

Comment: @AndreuAndon You need a JAX-RS implementation. If you plan to consume and produce JSON, you can use Jackson.